# Jquery code works, javascript does not, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is some code that has no jquery, but it is not working:

```
function start() {
var img = 0,
pic = ['nature', 'grass', 'earth', 'fall2', 'waterfall'],
slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slide_img'),
timerID = 0,
delay = 4000;

function back() {
    img--;
    if (img <= 0) {
        img = pic.length - 1;
    }
    slider.src = 'pictures/' + pic[img] + '.jpg';
}

function go() {
    img++;
    if (img >= pic.length) {
        img = 0;
    }
    slider.src = 'pictures/' + pic[img] + '.jpg';
}

document.getElementById('back').onclick = function() {
    back();
}

document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {
    go();
}

slider.onmouseenter = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
}

document.getElementById('go').onmouseenter = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
}

document.getElementById('back').onmouseenter = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
}

slider.onmouseleave = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    auto();
}

function auto() {
    timerID = setTimeout(function () {
        go();
        auto();
    }, delay);
}

auto();
```

}

Here is what it is in jquery, this one works:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
var img = 0,
pic = ['nature', 'grass', 'earth', 'fall2', 'waterfall'],
slider = $('img.slide_img'),
timerID = 0,
delay = 4000;

function back() {
    img--;
    if (img <= 0) {
        img = pic.length - 1;
    }
    slider.attr('src', 'pictures/' + pic[img] + '.jpg');
}

function go() {
    img++;
    if (img >= pic.length) {
        img = 0;
    }
    slider.attr('src', 'pictures/' + pic[img] + '.jpg');
}

$('button#back').on('click', function() {
    back();
});

$('button#go').on('click', function() {
    go();
});

$(slider).on('mouseenter', function () {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
});

$('button#go').on('mouseenter', function () {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
});

$('button#back').on('mouseenter', function () {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
});

$(slider).on('mouseleave', function () {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    auto();
});

function auto() {
    timerID = setTimeout(function () {
        go();
        auto();
    }, delay);
}

auto();
```

});

What am i doing wrong, why is the first one not working. Im am trying to get rid of jquery so i dont have to include the source file.

Comment: What's not working? What errors are displayed in your browser's error console?

Comment: Are you calling `start()` somewhere?

Comment: none, the buttons just didnt work, also the pictures would not change automaticly

Comment: <body onload="start"></body>

Comment: `slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slide_img');` gives you an array-like [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), you're using `slider` like a single element though. Vanilla JS doesn't make implicit iteration here, unlike jQuery, which iterates some of its objects automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing onload

try

```
var img = 0,
pic = ['nature', 'grass', 'earth', 'fall2', 'waterfall'],
slider,
timerID = 0,
delay = 4000;

window.onload=function() {
  slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slide_img');
  document.getElementById('back').onclick = function() {
    back();
  }

  document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {
    go();
  }

  slider.onmouseover = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
  }

  document.getElementById('go').onmouseover = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
  }

  document.getElementById('back').onmouseover = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
  }

  slider.onmouseout = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    auto();
  }
  auto();
}
function auto() {
    timerID = setTimeout(function () {
        go();
        auto();
    }, delay);
}
function back() {
    img--;
    if (img <= 0) {
        img = pic.length - 1;
    }
    slider.src = 'pictures/' + pic[img] + '.jpg';
}

function go() {
    img++;
    if (img >= pic.length) {
        img = 0;
    }
    slider.src = 'pictures/' + pic[img] + '.jpg';
}
```

Comment: the start function ran <body onload="start"></body>

Comment: The `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events have less browser support than their cousins `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: true - I am used to jQuery normalising all these

Comment: @mplungjan `slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slide_img');` & `slider.onmouseenter = ...` etc.

Comment: I changed some stuff, thanks all for helping, how do i delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

Use "onmouseover" and onmouseout" for canonical events:

```
slider.onmouseover = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
}

document.getElementById('go').onmouseover = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
}

document.getElementById('back').onmouseover = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
}

slider.onmouseout = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    auto();
}
```

And don't forget to define "slider" (the initial part is missing in your script):

```
var slider = document.querySelector('img.slide_img');
```

Answer (score 0):

> `<body onload="start"></body>`

The JavaScript `start` doesn't do anything. If you want to call a function, then you need to follow it with `()`.

This is a rather obtrusive way to deal with event handler assignment though. It is generally preferred to assign such things with JavaScript:

```
addEventListener('load', start);
```

See MDN for [compatibility notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility).

However, you don't have anything in your code that depends on the entire document being loaded. So you can simply:

```
    <script>
        start();
    </script>
</body>
```

at the end of your document.

(You can put the whole script there for that matter, and keep it in an external file).